# Pass permission from controller to javascript through blade

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel 7 with spatie laravel permission.

At the moment, I am passing the variable permission through compact to the blade with a form like:

```
$permission = Auth::user()->can('user-view');
if ($permission) then {$permission = 'true'} else {$permission = 'false'}
return view('user/show', compact('permission'));
```

And then in the blade I am using {{ $permission }} as a true or false for javascript.

It is working fine but I would like to find an easier way to do this so that I have to write less code. I imagine I could create a middleware to give to all view the list of all permissions and check if the Auth user has access to it and from there I would end up with an array with the key being the permission and the value being true or false.

I m just wondering if this is already existing.

Comment: You could use this in your blade `{{ auth()->user()->can('user-view') }}`, no need to pass it to the view.

Comment: yes but my problem is that when I use this, if it is false and I m using this in a javascript if then else, it doesn't print anything when false and it generates an error...

Comment: It returns a boolean, if you need a string you could do `{{ auth()->user()->can('user-view') ? 'true' : 'false' }}`

Comment: Thanks for that, I will go your way as it is less code to write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it directly in the view:

Returns a boolean:

```
{{ auth()->user()->can('user-view') }}
```

Returns a string:

```
{{ auth()->user()->can('user-view') ? 'true' : 'false' }}
```